# ng-repeat not working in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularfire

Here is my code I can"t get the values , presently three values are present but values are not displaying:

```
<body ng-controller="bucksbucket_orders">
    <form >
        <li ng-repeat="message in syncfromfbvalues">
            {{message.milk}},{{message.newspaper}},{{message.greens}}</li>
    </form>
</body>
```

Here is the values I try to get from firebase

```
values
 |--->greens: "56"
 |===> milk: "56"
 |===>newspaper: "56"
```

My app.js

```
var fbvalues = new Firebase("https://qwertyuiop.firebaseio.com/values");

$scope.defaultfbvalues = function () {
    fbvalues.set({
        "newspaper": '56',
        "milk": '56',
        "greens": '56'
    });
};

$scope.syncfromfbvalues = $firebaseArray(fbvalues);
```

my plunker demo : http://embed.plnkr.co/acFOlruX0t4bCIxXohAF/preview

Comment: If you just do `{{message}}` in your repeat what do you get?

Comment: does it work with scope.defaultfbvalues?

Comment: @ergonaut that wont work `defaultfbvalues` is a method adding something to `fbvalues`. Not the collection itself.

Comment: @ste2425

`{"$value":"56","$id":"greens","$priority":null}
{"$value":"56","$id":"milk","$priority":null}
{"$value":"56","$id":"newspaper","$priority":null}`

Comment: @RamanaaGj well that's your answer there then. Your array is not in the format you expect. I presume because  its a `Firebase` Array what ever that is.

Comment: @ste2425 can i provide you live demo in plunker.com ?

Comment: Sure add it to your question, it will help others. Either way what you added in the comment is the structure of your object. Because you didnt create it, `Firebase` did you have to conform to its formatting. Unless you map your array after `Firebase` created it. But then i presume that negates any benefits of using `Firebase`

Comment: @ste2425 my coding is correct but i can"t get the values ? any idea on it ?

Comment: Use console.log(syncfromfbvalues)  for display the object of return. I believe the format return is not a json, is text format

Comment: @EmirMarques how to use that console.log(syncfromfbvalues) ? sorry i"m new to js

Comment: Why are you using `ng-repeat` and `$firebaseArray` instead of `$firebaseObject`?

Comment: @RamanaaGj Put the console.log($scope.syncfromfbvalues)  after $scope.syncfromfbvalues = $firebaseArray(fbvalues). Open de console in browser. For this, click right mouse >> inspect element >> console. Refresh the page and run your programa. Look display console

Comment: @EmirMarques Marques  here is the plunker demo

http://embed.plnkr.co/acFOlruX0t4bCIxXohAF/preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$scope.defaultfbvalues = function () {
     fbvalues.set({
          "newspaper": '56',
          "milk": '56',
          "greens": '56'
     });
};
```

To:

```
$scope.defaultfbvalues = function () {
     fbvalues.set([{
          "newspaper": '56',
          "milk": '56',
          "greens": '56'
     }]);
};
```

The fbvalues is array "[ ]"

Comment: good it"s working fine but i figure out other way too !!! ...

`$scope.defaultfbvalues = function () {
     fbvalues.set({
          "newspaper": '56',
          "milk": '56',
          "greens": '56'
     });
};`  

to 


 `$scope.defaultfbvalues = function () {
     fbvalues.push({
          "newspaper": '56',
          "milk": '56',
          "greens": '56'
     });
};`


change the set value to push and also your code works fine too but  how can it created nested value as 0 ?

Comment: I not understand. Please question again?

Answer (score 0):

The AngularFire `$firebaseArray` is built to work with typical Firebase sequences, where the keys are in the form of `-J-0FSHRJ913A` and usually not displayed.

In your case, you'll want to display both the `$id` and `$value`:

```
<li ng-repeat="message in syncfromfbvalues">
    {{message.$id}} - {{message.$value}}
</li>
```

Which displays:

- greens - 56
- milk - 56
- newspaper - 56